# Select columns by name rather than letter in Google Query Language (GQL) with Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, gql

newbie question, is it possible to select columns by name rather than letter when using Google Query Language with Google Spreadsheets?

This works fine for me:   "SELECT A, COUNT(B) GROUP BY A"

It'd be great if I could use the column headers in the first row, more like a database, as in:

"SELECT student, COUNT(detention) GROUP BY student"

I suspect it's not possible, but hope this yet another case where my Internet search skills failed me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently not possible. The GQL documentation states[1] "Columns are referenced by the identifiers (not by labels). For example, in a Google Spreadsheet, column identifiers are the one or two character column letter (A, B, C, ...)."

If you want to do this in a spreadsheet it is possible with the following formula to convert a column header name into a letter (some tweaking might be required +1 (might be +2)). It also relies on column headers being unique and not containing commas

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(1,COUNTA(SPLIT(LEFT(JOIN(",",TRANSPOSE(1:1)),FIND("your_column_name",JOIN(",",TRANSPOSE(1:1)))),","))+1,4);"[a-zA-Z]+")
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Select

Answer (score 1):

I found that when you use `IMPORTRANGE` function on external ranges it converts from a letter to a column number, and will help you in this matter.

I've wanted to select a column based on its field name, but the problem for me was that the column to look at was likely to change in the future. So what I did was use the `MATCH` function to identify the column, so it looks something like

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet url","NamedRange"),"SELECT Col"&MATCH("FieldName",FieldNameRowAddress/RangeName,FALSE)")`

The funny thing is you have to allow permission to access itself.

I've named my ranges that I'm importing to make it even more future proof.

Answer (score 0):

A little simpler:

```
SELECT "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("student",Sheet1!A1:B1,0),4),1,"")&", COUNT("&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("detention",Sheet1!A1:B1,0),4),1,"")&") GROUP BY "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("student",Sheet1!A1:B1,0),4),1,"")
```

- [Example in Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bI33_-SjuQprCDEqTewWKCydU5Ks-zvQTyqtoauEDls/edit?usp=sharing)
- [Detailed explanation](http://mudd.com/blog/query-column-header-name-google-sheets/)

Answer (score 0):

if you really want you can fake it:

```
=LAMBDA(student, detention, QUERY({A1:B5}, 
 "SELECT "&student&", COUNT("&detention&") GROUP BY "&student, 1))
 ("Col"&MATCH("student",   A1:B1, ), 
  "Col"&MATCH("detention", A1:B1, ))
```

[image]