# Google spreadsheet "=QUERY" join() equivalent function?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-query-language

This question is concerning joining two databases in Google spreadsheet using =QUERY function

I have a table like so in range A1:C3

```
a d g
b e h
c f i
```

I have another table

```
c j m
a k n
b l o
```

I want the final table to look like this

```
a d g k n
b e h l o 
c f i j m
```

I can do this by using a vlookup function pretty easily in cell D1 and paste it down and across, but my dataset is huge. I would need a whole page of vlookups and Google Spreadsheet tells I'm at my limit in complexities.

I look at the Google's Query Language reference... there doesn't seem to be an type of "join" functions mentioned. You would think it would be an easy "join on A" type operation.

Can anybody solves this without a vlookup?

Comment: I am guessing that `index` and `match` would have the same complexity as vlookups, but you can try [this implementation](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EZc1kV4YQ2Ld8zagZ725xqSlCZKYOlgvV_eEejJ6K8s/edit#gid=0). If this does not work, then I think custom function needs to be written.

Comment: @Konstant. Thanks for the suggestion. Your solution also works. I think this question became a lot less relevant since the new Google sheets. Supposedly they have eliminated the number of complexities limits, but I still notice some problems for bigger sheets.

Comment: can you share me a sample sheet (with huge data) if possible. I will try to write a custom function for the same.

Comment: I can't share the data. I would think you recreate it with the `rand()` function

Comment: I just wanted to know the approx number of rows you have.

Comment: @Konstant about 20k rows

Comment: Could you mention how you'd do this for smaller data sets (the `vlookup` / `index` / `match` solutions)?

Comment: @ ruben. When is google going to rewrite their query function? seems like more and more people are using it, time to make it more robust!

Comment: @jason I didn't get a notification because the space between `@` and my displayname. AFAIK Google didn't announced that but it's worth to note that the official help article was made "more robust". I will add to my answer.

Comment: Didn't know about `vlookup`, and this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: You may also be interested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65363849/google-sheets-query-left-join/65368321#65368321 which demonstrates a one-to-many join (for small number of columns)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

## Short answer

[Google QUERY Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) version 0.7 (2016) doesn't include a JOIN (LEFT JOIN) operator but this could be achieved by using an array formula which result could be used as input for the QUERY function or for other uses.

## Explanation

Array formulas and the [array handling features of Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) make possible to make a JOIN between two simple tables. In order to make easier to read, the proposed formula use named ranges instead of range references.

### Named Ranges

- table1 : Sheet1!A1:C3
- table2 : Sheet2!A1:C3
- ID : Sheet1!A1:A3

### Formula

```
=ArrayFormula(
   {
     table1,
     vlookup(ID,table2,COLUMN(Indirect("R1C2:R1C"&COLUMNS(table2),0)),0)
   }
)
```

Remarks:

- Using open ended ranges is possible but this could make the spreadsheet slower.
- To speed up the recalculation time :

1. Replace `Indirect("R1C2:R1C"&COLUMNS(table2),0)` by an array of constants from 2 to number of columns of table2.
2. Remove the empty rows from the spreadsheet

## Example

See [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MF-lPdlptcgmBz5wiyo4Hjg1rxZatm5P82lCj_7h87g/edit#gid=92922776) for an example

## Note

On 2017 Google improved the official help article in English about QUERY, [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en). It still doesn't include yet topics like this but could be helpful to understand how it works.

Comment: For now this is the only answer here that actually works for large datasets without pasting formulas in each cell. It's really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: This is very clever. Is it possible to make this into an INNER JOIN?

Comment: @cjm2671: Thanks. If you didn't do this yet, please post a new question. This could be obvious, but anyway... If you add a link here I'll be able to find it easily :)

Comment: best answer I got so far

Comment: Thank you @Rubén, this is gold! Can you expand on what you mean by "...by an array of constants from 2 to number of columns of table2". I've tried to use {2,2} and variants as the substitute for the INDIRECT(...) without success

Comment: @OrenPinsky I suggest you to post a new question including sample data an the formula that you tried.

Comment: Found the solution @Rubén. I think you meant "Replace Indirect(.." by "Replace COLUMN(Indirect(..". I was able to get the result I needed using the following:

=ArrayFormula(
   {
     table1!A1:C3,
     vlookup(table1!A1:A3,table2!A1:C3,{2,3},0)
   }
)

Comment: In some languages a backslash should replace a comma. E.g.: =ArrayFormula({table1!A1:C3\  vlookup(table1!A1:A3;table2!A1:C3;COLUMN(Indirect("R1C2:R1C"&COLUMNS(table2!A1:C3);0));0)})

Comment: @CleberJorgeAmaral Rather than depending on the language depends on the regional setting (this is explained on the second link in the answer body)

Answer (score 23):

So, this answers how you do it WITH a Vlookup-function, but in only one cell.
In your example, given that each table of data has the following cell references:

Table1: Sheet1!A1:C3

```
a d g
b e h
c f i
```

Table2: Sheet2!A1:C3

```
c j m
a k n
b l o
```

This is how the formula should be constructed.

## **Join-formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(
   {
     Sheet1!A1:C,
     vlookup(Sheet1!A1:A, {Sheet2!A1:A, Sheet2!B1:C}, {2,3}, false)
   }
)
```

The key to get this formula to work, is to understand how to use curly brackets in the Vlookup Range. You basically define the first cell reference of the Range as the column which is to be a match to the Vlookup Search_Key. The rest of the cell references in the Range is in relation to the columns which you would like to join.

The Index is written as {2,3} to return the second and third column of the Range (the Range consists of a total of 3 columns); curly brackets has nothing to do with Arrayformula in the Vlookup Index, but is necessary to return multiple columns from the Vlookup function. The reason to not write {1,2,3} is because you would not like to include the column which is being used for the purpose of joining.

### Example where the column in table2 used for joining, is located in a different column (to the right of the data which is to be joined)

This kind of Join-formula can be utilized even if the join-column in the second table is located as the third column of that table.
Let's say that the raw-data in this example would look like this:

Table1 (Sheet1):

```
a d g
b e h
c f i
```

Table2 (Sheet2):

```
j m c
k n a
l o b
```

If you write the formula like this, you'll still get the desired outcome (as displayed in the table of joined data):

```
=ArrayFormula(
   {
     Sheet1!A1:C,
     vlookup(Sheet1!A1:A, {Sheet2!C1:C, Sheet2!A1:B}, {2,3}, false)
   }
)
```

The table of joined data:

```
a d g k n
b e h l o 
c f i j m
```

In the Join-formula, notice that the third column of Table2 is located as the first cell reference in the Vlookup Range!
The reason to why this works, is because when you use curly brackets in the Range (in conjunction with Arrayformula), the Vlookup Search_Key will NOT look for a column as a common denominator within the raw-data, instead it will use the Array within curly brackets as a reference to find a column as a common denominator (by default this is the first column of the Range).

I've written a comprehensive guide about this topic called:

#### ['Mastering Join-formulas in Google Sheets'](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14fVgEfdxsiBZGAqEP9qpySM1W28HEFzFYcXd6daNH38/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en) or YOU can just drag this formula:
after an import or `QUERY`-ing the first table; in the D column:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A1:C3, "Select B,C WHERE A='" & A1 & "'", 0)
```

Comment: Nice one. I don't understand why some documentations say QUERY has no join. It has maybe not the JOIN keyword but this answer is a join and it works well for me.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by using Javascript LINQ (language integrated query).

It lets you specify Javascript with complex join conditions.  You can also perform other SQL queries such as Grouping, Projecting, Sorting and Filtering your sheets as if they were database tables.  Look at the links below.

Note that in the LINQ query language I replaced all spaces in column names with underscores to make them valid JS identifiers.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DHtQlQUlo-X_YVfo-Wo-b7315sSk2pxL5ci4Y9lxvZo/edit?usp=sharing

https://script.google.com/d/1R5L2ReHJrBRwyoSoVOFLzEQZiGtxidPfPkAeVownt7SWX6TpacY7gA7j/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

If you can map each "index" (a, b, c) to a specific row or column, then you could use the [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) function.

In this case, you could probably map 'a' to column A (or row 1), 'b' to column B (or row 2), and so on.

Also, [Merge Tables](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171254?hl=en) seem to address this exact use case.

Comment: Merge Tables is a Fusion Tables function, not a Sheets function.

Answer (score -1):

With the 'other' table in A5:C7, please try:

```
=query({A1:C3,query(sort(A5:C7,1,TRUE),"Select Col2,Col3")})
```