# Join tables on Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I join 2 tables on Google Sheet using a column as a key reference?

I have my data on **Sheet1** and **Sheet2**.

What formula should I insert on **Sheet3!A1** to get this result?

---

**Sheet1**

```
|   | A          | B          |
| - | ---------- | ---------- |
| 1 | Date       | Task 1 (h) |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 1          |
| 3 | 2021-01-02 |            |
| 4 | 2021-01-04 | 1          |
| 5 | 2021-01-06 | 1          |
```

---

**Sheet2**

```
|   | A          | B          | C          |
| - | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 1 | Date       | Task 2 (h) | Task 3 (h) |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2          |            |
| 3 | 2021-01-03 |            | 3          |
| 4 | 2021-01-05 |            | 3          |
| 5 | 2021-01-06 |            |            |
```

---

**Sheet3**

```
|   | A          | B          | C          | D          |
| - | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 1 | Date       | Task 1 (h) | Task 2 (h) | Task 3 (h) |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 1          | 2          |            |
| 3 | 2021-01-02 |            |            |            |
| 4 | 2021-01-03 |            |            | 3          |
| 5 | 2021-01-04 | 1          |            |            |
| 6 | 2021-01-05 |            |            | 3          |
| 7 | 2021-01-06 | 1          |            |            |
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join tables in google sheet - full join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641416/join-tables-in-google-sheet-full-join)

Comment: It probably should, but I thought it would be WAY easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed answer above recommending the use an ARRAYFORMULA is far more complicated than it needs to be for your simple problem.

Search for tutorials on the INDEX-MATCH function. This  will allow you to perform the table join once you have the full key column.

To get the full key column, use the [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) function to feed in column A from both sheets to get a unique list of keys.

Comment: With this approach every desired cell in Sheet3 needs a formula in it, right?

Comment: Correct. You can autofill the formula from the first row down the entire sheet. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75509?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en