# google sheets query left join one-to-many

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have 2 tables and I am trying to perform a left join using google query language,or any formula that could output the result set.

Table1

[image]

Table2

[image]

Result set

[image]

How can I accomplish that ?

Regards

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title of the question to flag up that it is asking for a one-to-many relationship between the two tables (because ID=3 occurs twice in the second table and you want both rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK well here is an *inner join* to start with:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(iferror(split(flatten(if(transpose(filter(Table2!B2:B,Table2!B2:B<>""))=filter(Table1!A2:A,Table1!A2:A<>""),filter(Table1!A2:A,Table1!A2:A<>"")&"|"&transpose(filter(Table2!A2:A,Table2!A2:A<>"")),)),"|")),"select Col1,Col2 where Col1 is not null label Col1 '',Col2 ''"))
```

which builds up a 2D array and fills in the positions where the two sets of data match, then flattens it back into a 1D array and splits it back into two columns.

[image]

I think you just have to add the non-matching rows to get a left outer join:

```
=ArrayFormula({query(iferror(split(flatten(if(transpose(filter(Table2!B2:B,Table2!B2:B<>""))=filter(Table1!A2:A,Table1!A2:A<>""),
filter(Table1!A2:A,Table1!A2:A<>"")&"|"&transpose(filter(Table2!A2:A,Table2!A2:A<>"")),)),"|")),"select Col1,Col2 where Col1 is not null label Col1 '',Col2 ''");
filter(Table1!A2:B,isna(vlookup(Table1!A2:A,Table2!B2:B,1,false)))})
```

[image]

*Note*

This is a special case where the first table just consists of keys (ID), and you want just the key plus the other column from the second table for rows where the IDs match. It would be straightforward to add more columns separated by a pipe symbol (or any other character of choice), but these would have to be hard-coded: I don't know of any way with this approach to automatically include all columns from both tables.

This is in contrast to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796620/google-spreadsheet-query-join-equivalent-function?rq=1) which do automatically combine columns from both tables but don't allow for a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Hi Tom, fantastic solution. I couldn't get it myself. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Thanks! I will add a note to previous solutions to show this as a possible approach to one-to-many relationships https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796620/google-spreadsheet-query-join-equivalent-function?rq=1.

Answer (score 2):

I have also seen many solutions that have complicated formulas using `VLOOKUP`, `INDEX`, `MATCH`, etc.

I decided to write a user function to combine tables, or as I refer to it, de-normalize the database. I wrote the function `DENORMALIZE()` to support `INNER`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `FULL` joins. By nesting function calls one can join unlimited tables in theory.

```
DENORMALIZE(range1, range2, primaryKey, foreignKey, [joinType])
```

Parameters:

- `range1`, the main table as a named range, a1Notation or an array
- `range2`, the related table as a named range, a1Notation or an array
- `primaryKey`, the unique identifier for the main table, columns start with "1"
- `foreignKey`, the key in the related table to join to the main table, columns start with "1"
- `joinType`, type of join, "Inner", "Left", "Right", "Full", optional and defaults to "Inner", case insensitive

Returns: results as a two dimensional array

Result Set Example:

```
=QUERY(denormalize("Employees","Orders",1,3), "SELECT * WHERE Col2 = 'Davolio' AND Col8=2", FALSE)
```

| EmpID | LastName | FirstName | OrderID | CustomerID | EmpID | OrderDate | ShipperID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Davolio | Nancy | 10285 | 63 | 1 | 8/20/1996 | 2 |
| 1 | Davolio | Nancy | 10292 | 81 | 1 | 8/28/1996 | 2 |
| 1 | Davolio | Nancy | 10304 | 80 | 1 | 9/12/1996 | 2 |

Other Examples:

```
=denormalize("Employees","Orders",1,3)
=denormalize("Employees","Orders",1,3,"full")
=QUERY(denormalize("Employees","Orders",1,3,"left"), "SELECT * ", FALSE)
=QUERY(denormalize("Employees","Orders",1,3), "SELECT * WHERE Col2 = 'Davolio'", FALSE)
=QUERY(denormalize("Employees","Orders",1,3), "SELECT * WHERE Col2 = 'Davolio' AND Col8=2", FALSE)
=denormalize("Orders","OrderDetails",1,2)
// multiple joins 
=denormalize("Employees",denormalize("Orders","OrderDetails",1,2),1,3)
=QUERY(denormalize("Employees",denormalize("Orders","OrderDetails",1,2),1,3), "SELECT *", FALSE)
=denormalize(denormalize("Employees","Orders",1,3),"OrderDetails",1,2)
=QUERY(denormalize("Employees",denormalize("Orders","OrderDetails",1,2),1,3), "SELECT *", FALSE)
=QUERY(denormalize(denormalize("Employees","Orders",1,3),"OrderDetails",4,2), "SELECT *", FALSE)

function denormalize(range1, range2, primaryKey, foreignKey, joinType) {
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var index = -1;
  var lFound = false;
  var aDenorm = [];
  var hashtable = [];
  var aRange1 = "";
  var aRange2 = "";
  joinType = DefaultTo(joinType, "INNER").toUpperCase();
  // the 6 lines below are used for debugging
  //range1 = "Employees";
  //range1 = "Employees!A2:C12";
  //range2 = "Orders";
  //primaryKey = 1;
  //foreignKey = 3;
  //joinType = "LEFT";
  // Sheets starts numbering columns starting with "1", arrays are zero-based
  primaryKey -= 1;
  foreignKey -= 1;
  // check if range is not an array
  if (typeof range1 !== 'object') {
    // Determine if range is a1Notation and load data into an array
    if (range1.indexOf(":") !== -1) {
      aRange1 = ss.getRange(range1).getValues();
    } else {
      aRange1 = ss.getRangeByName(range1).getValues();
    } 
  } else {
    aRange1 = range1;
  }
  
  if (typeof range2 !== 'object') {
    if (range2.indexOf(":") !== -1) {
      aRange2 = ss.getRange(range2).getValues();
    } else {
      aRange2 = ss.getRangeByName(range2).getValues();
    }
  } else {
    aRange2 = range2;
  }
  
  // make similar structured temp arrays with NULL elements
  var tArray1 = MakeArray(aRange1[0].length);
  var tArray2 = MakeArray(aRange2[0].length);
  var lenRange1 = aRange1.length;
  var lenRange2 = aRange2.length;
  hashtable = getHT(aRange1, lenRange1, primaryKey);
  for(i = 0; i < lenRange2; i++)  {
    index = hashtable.indexOf(aRange2[i][foreignKey]);
    if (index !== -1) {
      aDenorm.push(aRange1[index].concat(aRange2[i]));
    }
  }
  // add left and full no matches
  if (joinType == "LEFT" || joinType == "FULL") {
    for(i = 0; i < lenRange1; i++)  {
      //index = aDenorm.indexOf(aRange1[i][primaryKey]);
      index = aScan(aDenorm, aRange1[i][primaryKey], primaryKey)
      if (index == -1) {
        aDenorm.push(aRange1[i].concat(tArray2));
      }
    }
  }
  // add right and full no matches
  if (joinType == "RIGHT" || joinType == "FULL") {
    for(i = 0; i < lenRange2; i++)  {
      index = aScan(aDenorm, aRange2[i][foreignKey], primaryKey)
      if (index == -1) {
        aDenorm.push(tArray1.concat(aRange2[i]));
      }
    }
  }
    return aDenorm;
}

function getHT(aRange, lenRange, key){
var aHashtable = [];
var i = 0;
for (i=0; i < lenRange; i++ ) {
  //aHashtable.push([aRange[i][key], i]);
  aHashtable.push(aRange[i][key]);
  }
return aHashtable;
}

function MakeArray(length) {
  var i = 0;
  var retArray = [];
  for (i=0; i < length; i++) {
    retArray.push("");
  }
  return retArray;
}

function DefaultTo(valueToCheck, valueToDefault) {
return typeof valueToCheck === "undefined" ? valueToDefault : valueToCheck;
}

// Search a multi-dimensional array for a value
function aScan(aValues, searchStr, searchCol) {
var retval = -1;
var i = 0;
var aLen   = aValues.length;
for (i = 0; i < aLen; i++) {
    if (aValues[i][searchCol] == searchStr) {
        retval = i;
        break;
    }
}
return retval;
}
```

You can make a copy of the google sheet with data and examples here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vziuF8gQcsOxTLEtlcU2cgTAYL1eIaaMTAoIrAS7mnE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Excellent work @JohnA! This solution is better because it makes a base that could be expanded easily

Comment: It didn't work because you used `ss` without defining it, so I've added `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` (the edit needs to be approved).

Comment: Actually I did define it as a public constant at the top of the script
.
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

Answer (score 1):

use in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(Table1!A2:A, {Table2!B:B, Table2!A:A}, 2, 0)))
```